# $6$ coins are tossed. What is the probability that at least $4$ show tails?

Tags: probability

The problem is that

> $6$ coins are tossed.what is the probability that at least $4$ show tails?

Can someone please verify if I am doing this right:

$$\frac{\mathrm C(6,4) + \mathrm C(6,5) + \mathrm C(6,6)}{64}$$

which is equal to $22/64$ which simplifies to $11/32$.

Comment: Looks good.${}{}$.

Comment: Thanks, got confused, cause on a previous post similar to this, the people said 21/64

Comment: They might have been answering a slightly different question, or there was a mistake. Anyway, if you ever want to give more details, it would help if you format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to answers.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

Your answer is correct.